# I can't find "Node Viewer" in 3.3

Tags: node-editor

I have the Node wrangler addon enabled, but when I use "shift + ctrl + left mouse", the  node viewer not appear, but connects in a straight line, but by pressing "shift + ctrl + right mouse" the node mix appears....
I have searched all the sites with the same problem, but no one has written any solutions that

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEgzuMmJtu8&t=8s) I tried to make a tree based on this video, but I need a node viewer there, do I need to install an old version of the blender for this thing??? wt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node Viewer used to be just a simple Emission shader named "Node Viewer" by the Node Wrangler add-on. Since current version displays a texture plugged in straight to Output as emission, it is no longer needed. If you need an emission shader, you can find it in Add -> Shader menu:

[image]

You can change the name displayed on the top of any node by changing its label:
[image]